# Retroactively binding URL query string parameters to objects in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a generic controller with many methods, supporting various query parameter combinations and media types.  When subclassing this controller, I would like to add some additional query string parameter bindings.  However, since it is not possible to override `@RequestMapping` annotations, it would seem that the best thing to do would be to have an overriding method that takes the `HttpServletRequest` from each method and spits out the customized mapped objects:

```
public class GenericController<T,ID>{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
        produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public HttpEntity findById(HttpServletRequest request){
        Map<String,Object> params = queryStringToParams(request.getParameterMap());
        List<T> results = repository.find(params);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(results, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    protected Map<String,Object> queryStringToParams(Map<String,String[]> qsParams){
        // magic happens here
    }

}
```

My question: is it possible to leverage the capabilities of the existing argument resolvers that Spring uses to transform `@RequestParam` parameters after the controller method arguments have been resolved?  The functionality for converting query string-formatted string arguments to Java objects is clearly already implemented here, it would be silly to have to write my own object mappers.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I am looking for is Spring's [ConversionService](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/ConversionService.html).  I can achieve the desired effect of parameter binding by either injecting the container's existing `ConversionService`...

```
@Autowired ConversionService conversionService;

...
Float number = conversionService.convert((String) qsParams.get("number")[0], Float.class);
...
```

... which has the benefit of including any custom converters that may have been created.  Alternatively, I can use the default `ConversionService` implementation, `DefaultConversionService`:

```
ConversionService conversionService = new DefaultConversionService();
```